# Solve ÿ end of file in C

Tags: c, eof

When I copy the content of a file to another in C at the end of the output file I have this character `ÿ`. I understand thanks to this forum that it is the EOF indicator but I don't understand what to do in order to get rid of it in the output file.

This is my code:

```
second_file = fopen(argv[2], "w+");
while (curr_char != EOF)
{
    curr_char = fgetc(original_file);
    fputc(curr_char, second_file);
}
printf("Your file has been successfully copy\n");
fclose(second_file);
fclose(original_file);
```

Comment: Well it's pretty obvious, you've stored the EOF, stop doing that.

Comment: You should test for EOF after reading a character and before writing it.  Here, you read a character, write it, and *then* test for EOF.

Comment: `while((c = fgetc(fpin)) != EOF) fputc(c, fpout);`

Comment: Consider using a buffer with `fread` and `fwrite` instead of character-by-character I/O for efficiency, anyway.

Comment: You should just add a "t" to the mode you specify to the fopen call when opening original_file, assuming your code is running on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each character you read, you have two things to do:

1. Check to see if it's EOF.
2. If not, write it to the output.

Your problem is you're doing these two things in the wrong order.

There are potentially several different ways of solving this.  Which one you pick depends on how much you care about your program looking good, as opposed to merely working.

One. Starting with the code you wrote, we could change it to:

```
while (curr_char != EOF)
    {
    curr_char = getc(original_file);
    if(curr_char == EOF) break;
    putc(curr_char, second_file);
    }
```

Here, we explicitly test to see if the character is EOF, immediately after reading it, before writing it.  If it's EOF, we break out of the loop early.  This will work, but it's ugly: there are two different places where we test for EOF, and one of them never "fires".  (Also, as a commentator reminded me, there's the problem that the first time through the loop, we're testing `curr_char` before we've ever set it.)

Two.  You could rearrange it like this:

```
curr_char = getc(original_file);
while (curr_char != EOF)
    {
    putc(curr_char, second_file);
    curr_char = getc(original_file);
    }
```

Here, we read an initial character, and as long as it's not EOF, we write it and read another.  This will work just fine, but but it's still a little bit ugly, because this time there are two different places where we read the character.

Three.  You could rearrange it like this:

```
while ((curr_char = getc(original_file)) != EOF)
    {
    putc(curr_char, second_file);
    }
```

This is the conventional way of writing a character-copying loop in C.  The call to `getc` and the assignment to `curr_char` are buried inside of the controlling expression of the `while` loop.  It depends on the fact that in C, an assignment expression has a value just like any other expression.  That is, the value of the expression `a = b` is whatever value we just assigned to `a` (that is, `b`'s value).  So the value of the expression `curr_char = getc(original_file)` is the character we just read.  So when we say `while ((curr_char = getc(original_file)) != EOF)`, what we're actually saying is, "Call `getc`, assign the result to `curr_char`, and if it's not equal to `EOF`, take another trip around the loop."

(If you're still having trouble seeing this, I've written other explanations in [these notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/sx4f.html) and [this writeup](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx6b.html).)

This code is both good and bad.  It's good because we've got exactly one place we read characters, one place we test characters, and one place we write characters.  But it's a little bit bad because, let's admit it, it's somewhat cryptic at first.  It's hard to think about that assignment-buried-inside-the-`while`-condition.  It's code like this that gives C a reputation as being full of obscure gobbledegook.

But, at least in this case, it really is worth learning the idiom, and becoming comfortable with it, because the reductions to just one read and one test and one write really *are* virtues.  It doesn't matter so much in a trivial case like this, but in real programs which are complicated for other reasons, if there's some key piece of functionality that happens in two different places, it's extremely easy to overlook this fact, and to make a change to one of them but forget to make it to the other.

(In fact, this happened to me just last week at work.  I was trying to fix a bug in somebody else's code.  I finally figured out that when the code did X, it was inadvertently clearing Y.  I found the place where it did X, and I added some new code to properly recreate Y.  But when I tested my fix, it didn't work!  It turned out there were two separate places where the code did X, and I had found and fixed the wrong one.)

Finally, here's an equivalently minimal but unconventional way of writing the loop:

```
while (1)
    {
    curr_char = getc(original_file);
    if(curr_char == EOF) break;
    putc(curr_char, second_file);
    }
```

This is kind of like number 1, but it gets rid of the redundant condition in the `while` loop, and replaces it with the constant `1`, which is "true" in C.  This will work just fine, too, and it shares the virtue of having one read, one test, and one write.  It actually ends up doing exactly the same operations and in exactly the same order as number 3, but by being laid out linearly it may be easier to follow.

The only problem with number 4 is that it's an unconventional, "break in the middle" loop.  Personally, I don't have a problem with break-in-the-middle loops, and I find they come up from time to time, but if I wrote one and someone said "Steve, that's ugly, it's not an idiom anyone recognizes, it will confuse people", I'd have to agree.

P.S. I have replaced your calls to `fgetc` and `fputc` with the more conventional `getc` and `putc`.  I'm not sure who told you to use `fgetc` and `fputc`, and there are obscure circumstances where you need them, but they're so rare that in my opinion one might as well forget that the "f" variants exist, and always use `getc` and `putc`.

Comment: Your method #1 is *unsafe* as it checks `curr_char` before being initialized!

Comment: Thanks you very much, but can you explain in the example 3 why if I put the call of getc and the assignment to curr_char inside of the controlling expression of the while loop it is like I do  if(curr_char == EOF) break;

Comment: @RonyCohen The result of an assignment is whatever value is assigned.  The result of the assignment in this case is `getc(original_file)`. Then you compare that to EOF.

Comment: @RonyCohen See the expanded answer.